# [_UIBarItemAppearance setTitleColor:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit

I'm trying to set the title color for all `UIBarButtonItem`s

When I use:

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleColor:normalTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I get :

```
-[_UIBarItemAppearance setTitleColor:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd695e30
```

I didn't have any problems with background image but title color isn't working so well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because it doesn't exist in the class [UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or in it's [super class](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)

You can use this method define in [UIBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)

```
 setTitleTextAttributes:forState:
```

Sets the title’s text attributes for a given control state.

```
- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forState:(UIControlState)state
```

**Parameters**
**attributes**

A dictionary containing key-value pairs for text attributes.
***You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset using the keys listed in NSString UIKit Additions Reference.***
**state**

The control state for which you want to set the text attributes for the title.
**Availability**
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
See Also

```
– titleTextAttributesForState:
```

Declared In

```
UIBarItem.h
```

Comment: This is also the solution to the similar problem of "setTitleTextAttributes" throwing unrecognized selector at run time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick addendum to the accepted answer, and to save some time for those actually looking to implement this, the constant for text color is UITextAttributeTextColor.

In the latest xcode, which allows you to create object literals, you can easily set the text appearance for the buttons as follows.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor redColor] }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the appearanceWhenContainedIn method of UILabel, for instance if you want to customize a UITabBarItem :

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12]];
```